# Greatest Common Denominator counter

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I wanted to make a greatest common divisor counter in python, but I'm not exactly sure how to go at it, or where to start... Pretty much all I've got is this equation (a and b are numbers):

```
a = b * quotient + remainder
```

And I want the counter to print all the steps until remainder is lower than a, and then show the GCD.

I've also searched some more and found out that quotient of 2 numbers can be simply done with the // command and remainder with % command, so basically:

```
a = b * (a // b) + (a % b)
```

I'm also aware that I need a loop for the counter, but I've got no idea how to go about that... Help would be most appreciated.

I've seen some codes for GCD, but couldn't find one that would show all the steps.

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop in Python to begin with?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations provides some pseudocode implementations which are almost valid python.

Comment: I only know the "while" loop and I think it would be the right one for this example. I just have no idea what to put in as conditions... While (a % b) > a?

Comment: Are you on Python 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: @PrimozMenges: is there something missing from my answer? If yes, just please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def gcd_steps(a, b):
    steps = []
    # this is the standard GCD finding algorithm;
    # we simply amend it with "step tracking"
    while b:
        # a, b = b, a % b
        tmp = a
        a = b
        b = tmp % b
        steps.append(a)
    return steps  # normally we'd want to return `a`
                  # but you want the steps not just the result

steps = gcd_steps(125 * 123 * 12314, 25 * 149)

# print the list with `->` between the steps
print(" -> ".join(str(x) for x in steps))
```

(the result would be the last step, which you can access by taking the last element of the list: `steps[-1]`)

**Output:**

```
3725 -> 900 -> 125 -> 25
```

Comment: Thanks, though this is way too advanced for me, I got lost at line 7... I'm completely new to python and all. Just wanted to know if there was a was an easier way to do it (with =, *, %, // and the loop and easier things like that) not necessarily a shorter way though.

Comment: If you find my code "too advanced" then **please** learn Python before you attept to solve even basic problems with it... because the code above is really damn simple... and it's even commented as much as possible. You can start here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Comment: ...I've actually made it even simpler for you.

Comment: So what exactly are you expecting here? Code that's simple enough for you? Or that somebody gives you a Python tutorial?

Comment: I appreciate the help, Erik. And yes I was expecting (or hoping) for a simpler code. learnphthonthehardway here I come...

Comment: @PrimozMenges: Again, if you were looking for "even simpler code", there's no use hanging out here and instead you should be spending several days to learn Python. So good luck with the book; hope you enjoy it.